# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE - Cordova Couchabse-Lite Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle, cordova-plugins

When I add the couchbase lite cordova plugin from:

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin

I get this error when building:

```
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
        File 1: C:\JavaScript\Project-Angular\platforms\android\libs\jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar
        File 2: C:\JavaScript\Project-Angular\platforms\android\libs\jackson-databind-2.5.0.jar

You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
        android {
          packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
          }
        }
```

I know it has something to do with the build.gradle file but I've searched everywhere and all the questions are about Android directly. I don't know how I'm supposed to edit the build.gradle file since its edited.

Removing the plugin fixes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem, you must create a file called **platforms/android/build-extras.gradle** within your project.  With that file created, you can paste the following code:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

The next time you try to build and run your project for Android, you should no longer suffer from that problem.

Further documentation on Apache Cordova's **build-extras.gradle** file can be found in the official documentation:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/android/tools.html

Best,